# Changing from int:pk to Slug

Tags: django

After finalizing my blog project I found out a way a switch from writing the id of the blog to writing a function to add the post title to become a slug.

So I am currently trying to switch all my post detail to slug but after I finished everything I am getting a page error 404 which doesn't indicate exactly where I have something wrong with my code.

My question is when I move from changing the urls from int:id to slug what should I be looking for to change as well to avoid page error 404?

In the URL for every page detail I am getting the int:id not the title of the post and the error 404

I have commented the addition of the slug function:
Here is the models.py :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='liked')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=120)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if not self.slug:
             self.slug = slugify(self.title)
         super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("score:post-detail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Here is the views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['slug'])  <- Error is coming here
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if stuff.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        return context


def LikeView(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True

    context = {
        'total_likes': post.total_likes,
        'liked': liked,
        'post': post
    }

    if request.is_ajax:
        html = render_to_string('like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

here is the url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('<slug:slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('<slug:slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete')
```

Comment: In a `DetailView`, or `UpdateView`, it does not make much difference, since these views look both for a `pk` and a `slug` in the URL, so changing it will change the query to `slug=...`.

Comment: The question is do you existing records already *have* a slug (that contains content, not just `NULL` or the empty string)?

Comment: I deleted all posts and created new ones for testing and they did not have slugs

Comment: @AhmedyKhairy: perhaps it is better to make use of an `AutoSlugField` (from `django-autoslug` https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I have used the AutoSlugField  but the same error was raised by ` score.views.PostDetailView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a problem with the slug.
What happens if you publish two posts with the same title?
Since they will be slugified in the same way you lose the uniqueness of the publications.
I advise you to cheat on the stackoverflow model which combines id and the slugified title like what appear in your browser.

Secondly,Your paths are confusing it's better to prefix with values ​​like detail/"pk" or question/"pk"/"slug"

I think the errors come from urls and this:

```
stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Replace it by:

```
stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Or better:

```
stuff = self.get_object()
```

Finally, In case you decide to follow my advice after adding the url like this for example:

```
path('details/<int:pk>-<slug:sl>', views.PostDetailView.as_view())
```

You will have to override the get_object() method of DetailView

```
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk,slug=slug)
        return stuff
```

Instead of postfixing the constant part of the url like this:

```
 path('<slug:slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
 path('<slug:slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete')
```

Do it like this it will help django to tell the difference between your urls

```
 path('update/<slug:slug>', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post- 
  update'),
 path('delete/<slug:slug>/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post- 
 delete')
```

And also avoid taking the argument at the beginning of the url as:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

Do this instead

```
path('posts/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: it is really helpful, there is something that i might have missed in the question and is that there is a get_absolute_url, I added it to the question it might be the reason for the error to still occur

Comment: get_absolute_url isn't the problem. I will try to explain

Comment: Instead of:
 path('<slug:slug>/update/',    PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'), path('<slug:slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView)

Do this:
 path('update/<slug:slug>',    PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'), path('delete/<slug:slug>', PostDeleteView)

Else where everytime you try to reach an url like localhost:8000/new/ the "new" will be considered as slug argument because of path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'), 

 This is why you may prefixed the url with constant part.

Comment: To prevent urls from being intertwined and helps django makes differences between urls. Sorry if it is unreadable I'm responding from my phone

Comment: if you could update it in your answer as it is unreadable thanks

Comment: I have update my response no time yersterday because of Aïd el-Fitr